# Any Way to Process Columns using MySQL from csv?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, codeigniter, networking

I have a csv file that has an ipv4 network and mask in a form like: 41.74.160.0/20

I want to separate this into the network long and the broadcast long so that I can check other longs that are within this range for matching purposes from another table. So far, I have stored it as just a string, since INET_ATON takes in a string, but I recently found out that it doesn't support the mask. I have also been using LOAD DATA INFILE as my solution for easily getting all the data in the table.

However, in this new solution, the columns in my table will obviously not match the ones in my data. Is there any way to load data with processing on columns from csv files in MySql? If not, is there an easy way to do it in PHP?

Comment: what preprocessing do you want on 41.74.160.0/20 is this 41.74.160.0 up to 41.74.160.20 ?

Comment: You could import the data into a staging table as strings and then process it with a stored procedure that transforms it and puts it into the real table.

Comment: Yes, it would be 41.74.160.0 up to 41.74.160.20 @futureweb

Comment: A staging table is a good idea, but my input data is rather large, so I worry about that extra step being too lengthy/large. If there is no other option, I will probably do something like that @stickybit

Comment: Load data infile can transform data in a row, but cannot generate a new row, which you appear to need. If you want to use mysql only, you must use a staging table. With php (or any other programming language), you can read your csv file line by line and generate the rows on the fly and insert the rows into mysql (or any other database). Whichever solution you choose, it needs to go through your data line by line and generate many rows, so it is not going to be quick if you have a big file. ETL processes do take time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can pre-process input from CSV files, and if I've understood your requirement, this is a simple string manipulation problem. `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` can extract the IP address and mask based on `/` as a separator.

Starting with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ipAddresses` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ipComplete` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ipAddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ipMask` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `fieldName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `inetNumeric` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And this CSV input:

```
"A field 1",41.74.160.0/20
"A field 2",41.74.160.1/20
"A field 3",41.74.160.2/20
"A field 4",41.74.160.3/20
```

This query:

```
load data infile '/sqlfiles/ips.csv' into table ipAddresses 
    columns terminated by ',' 
    enclosed by '"' 
    lines terminated by '\n'
    (fieldName, @ip) 
    set ipComplete = @ip, 
        ipAddress = substring_index(@ip,'/',1), 
        ipMask = substring_index(@ip,'/',-1), 
        inetNumeric = inet_aton(substring_index(@ip,'/',1));
```

Gives this result:

```
# id    ipComplete      ipAddress    ipMask fieldName   inetNumeric
29      41.74.160.0/20  41.74.160.0  20     A field 1   692756480
30      41.74.160.1/20  41.74.160.1  20     A field 2   692756481
31      41.74.160.2/20  41.74.160.2  20     A field 3   692756482
32      41.74.160.3/20  41.74.160.3  20     A field 4   692756483
```